# Destroying multiple records using select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to allow users to select multiple records to destroy in my rails 3 app.

I have a check_box_tag in my products index as follows:

```
 <td><%= check_box_tag "product_ids_destroy[]", product.id %></td>
```

And added a submit tag in my index:

```
<%= submit_tag "Delete Selected" %>
```

And in my products controller I created a method:

```
  def destroy_select
    product_ids = params["product_ids_destroy"]
    objs = Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["products.id IN (?)", product_ids])
    objs.each { |o| o.destroy}
  end
```

And defined my routes.rb:

```
  resources :products do
    collection do
      delete 'destroy_select'
    end
```

The method works in console. How do I "connect" the product_ids I collect from my index to the controller method to destroy each record? Can I add the method as an option in the submit tag? Also, if I wanted to add a confirm before destroy, do I add this to my submit tag?

Answer (score 0):

check your routes using

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

then on your form you can set the action of the form to that named route and the method to delete

you can do a tiny refactor of your controller's action

```
def destroy_select
  Product.destroy_all(params["product_ids_destroy"]) unless params["product_ids_destroy"].blank?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To hook that form submission into the right action in your controller, you're going to have to make the form use the DELETE method.  That option (`:method => :delete`) has to be set in your `form_for` or `form_tag` function call.

You can hook your confirmation message onto the `submit_tag` itself, though.  Check out the `:confirm => 'My message?'` option in [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag).

Hope that helps!